# How can I run Score Label when I touch the object?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I added Score Label in my game. But It doesn't run. When I touch the ball, Score should be increase. I couldn't connect ball with score label. Can anyone help me? Here is my code :

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
      super.didMoveToView(view)



    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)


    borderBody.friction = 0

    self.physicsBody = borderBody



    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(5, 5)

    let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
    ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(10, -10))

    scoreLabel.fontName = "Helvetica Neue Light"
    scoreLabel.text = "Score: 0"
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 40
    scoreLabel.color = SKColor.redColor()
    scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Left
    scoreLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.Top
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: size.height -  100)
    addChild(scoreLabel)



 }
```

And there is touch code :

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch:AnyObject in touches{
        let location = (touch as! UITouch).locationInNode(self)
        let nodeTouched = nodeAtPoint(location)
        let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode


     //Detect if the ball is touched
        if(nodeTouched == ball){

            physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(-30, 30)
        }

}
```

Comment: just change `scoreLabel.text` whenever the ball is touched

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand your comment. How should I change scoreLabel.text?

Comment: seems like you have the code that detects when the ball is touched, so you can simply update the score label there. unless I am misunderstanding your intentions.

Comment: try putting `scoreLabel.text = "Score: 1"` within your if statement

Comment: I couldn't think that. Thanks for help

Comment: No problem. And btw, good practice would be to store the score in an integer variable and increase that instead of updating the label text. Then you can just display this variable's value in the label.

Comment: Are you working on Computer Science GCSE too? This seems very similar to our project :)

Comment: @GabrielJones I'm working for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
     if ((nodeTouched.name?.containsString(BallCategoryName)) != nil) {

        //Update Score

     }
```

Keep in mind that we don't know exactly what BallCategoryName is or how you set it up, so you have to make sure it isn't nil.

Also, if your current method in `touchesBegan` is running your `physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(-30, 30)` line successfully, then we would know that something is wrong with your `scoreLabel` property and not the touch detection method.

If it was me, I would just make `ball` a property of your scene and then test it like so in `touchesBegan`:

```
if self.ball.containsPoint(touchLocation) {
    //Update Score
}
```